# Maven hanging indefinitely while checking for updates

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I'm building a project using maven (at which I am a novice) and it's hanging:

```
$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Presentation Reports
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] artifact org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin: checking for updates from central
```

This command has been doing the job without issue for a while, I didn't [knowingly?] change anything and it has begun hanging at that point (even left it overnight and it didn't budge).

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.7.0_25
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.5.0-23-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

I'll be honest, I'd be hugely impressed if anyone pinpointed the problem with just this information but any pointers in the right direction would be hugely helpful, searching around yielded nothing and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: can you run this command and post the entire output `mvn clean package -X`

Comment: I'm not sure why it's hanging, but I'd suggest specifying a version for your plugins in the pom.xml. This should prevent maven from checking for updates (which can also make your builds faster), but it also makes your build more robust because plugin versions are locked down. Once you've locked down plugin versions, you can use the versions-maven-plugin to keep them up to date.

Comment: @Jigar thank you, that helped me uncover the problem actually, an artifactory process that needed restarting.

Comment: Also @Martin, your comments appreciated and duly noted.

Comment: I will post it as an answer for reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

looks like it hangs while downloading, to see the exact point where it hangs please run

```
mvn clean package -X -e
```

that will give you debug level logging detail

from the comments it needed a restart of artifactory process

Comment: Yes, thanks. Restarting artifactory and Hudson servers worked for me.